# Bootchart for CoreOS?

Tags: logging, boot, coreos

is there a possibility to use Bootchart or any comparable tool to log booting times and services on a CoreOS machine?
So far I used 'dmesg' but was hoping to find something more graphic to better compare it to the values of other OS like Ubuntu.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `systemd-analyze`: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html

> systemd-analyze may be used to determine system boot-up performance statistics and retrieve other state and tracing information from the system and service manager, and to verify the correctness of unit files.